# Convert heap implemented in array to tree

Tags: c, algorithm, tree, heap, min-heap

I have this homework where I have to convert a min-heap represented in array:

```
DEFINE #SIZE

typedef int Heap[SIZE]
```

and implement it in a tree like so:

```
typedef struct node{
   int val;
   struct no *left, *right;
} Node, *Tree;
```

and as a reminder the index of min-heaps arrays is as follows:

```
#DEFINE PARENT(i) (i-1)/2
#DEFINE LEFT(i) 2*i + 1
#DEFINE RIGHT(i) 2*i + 2
```

so, how do I do this?

I started on something like this:

```
Tree heapToTree(int * heap){
   Tree *t = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   t->val = heap[0];
   Tree *aux = t; //save initial tree position
   for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
      aux->left=malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
      aux->left->val=heap[i*2 +1];
      aux->right=malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
      aux->right->val=heap[i*2 +2];
}
```

Am I on the right path? I think this should be done recursively, but how?

thanks in advance

Comment: what is `struct no`?

Comment: Heap is *a* (kind of) tree...

Comment: i.e. I don't get why you'd want to convert a tree that has a compact representation to a tree that doesn't have a compact representation.

Comment: It's homework. I guess it for better understanding of the subject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one thing that you are lacking is - not making the newly created node's links (`left` and `right`) to the `NULL` initially. No matter what, any kind of tree implementation this is very useful - helps in traversal, finding an element (which is again a traversal) etc.

Also in the loop you didn't change the value of `aux` (or atleast you didn't show) - as a result you are writing over the old values and having memory leak.

Apart from that not checking the return value of `malloc` is another point. You should check the return value of `malloc` - if `NULL` then you should handle that distinctly (error handling) from that of usual code flow.

Considering that heap is implemented in an array (0-index) you can do this to convert it to tree.

```
struct node *convIntoTree(int pos,int sz, int *heap){
    if(pos >= sz ) return NULL;
    struct node* root = malloc(sizeof *root);
    if( root == NULL ){
       perror("Malloc failed");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    root->data = heap[pos];
    root->left = convIntoTree(pos*2+1,sz);
    root->right = convIntoTree(pos*2+2,sz);
    return root;  
}
```

Call it like this

```
   struct node *root = convToTree(0,heapsize,heap);
```

The solution is simply applying a brute force method of traversing every node of the heap and then allocate memory for it and populate it's left and right child recursively.

Comment: @Richard.: Check it.

Comment: good ideia setting the index as the parameter. Thank you very much